# Processing/Java pixel array slicing assignment

Tags: java, arrays, processing, slice, pixel

I'm am using processing / Java and i am using the pixel array to assign a color to every pixel,  but the framerate is way too low if I assign every pixel so I want to treat a block of 5 pixels as one, so make them the same color.   I am nog doing this,

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 5) {
    // for loop width
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y += 5) {
        // For loop height
        // Assigning pixel color
        for (int px = 0; px < 5; px++) {
            for (int py = 0; py < 5; py++) {
                pixels[x + px + (y + py) * width] = color(myCol);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I wanted to know if I can assign a slice of the array something like this

```
pixels[startIndex : endIndex] = color(myColor);
```

Comment: No. Java has no syntactic construct to set a range of an array to a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

Processing does have a `set()` function that takes an image parameter. From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/set_.html):

```
size(100, 100);
PImage myImage = loadImage("apples.jpg");
set(0, 0, myImage);
line(0, 0, width, height);
line(0, height, width, 0);
```

[image: generated image]
<sub>(source: [processing.org](https://processing.org/reference/images/set_2.png))</sub>

You could put your color into an image, and then draw the image. I don't know whether this will be any faster or not.

Another option would be to simply resize the input image at startup.

Comment: Is it possible to draw, a frame and then resize it to 5 times as big and then display it?

Comment: @R.Versnel Yes. See the `createGraphics()` function in the reference.